# JS код, помощь в отладке

Tags: javascript

Написал скрипт, задача которого найти на станице все элементы с классом .product  и менять миниатюры при наведении мыши, но что - то работает он не так как ожидалось....

Вопросы в комментариях кода, который прилагаю ниже.

```
function Product(elem, imagesBox) {
    this.product = elem;
    if(!this.product) {
        return;
    } else {
        self = this;
        this.imagesBox = this.product.querySelector(imagesBox);
        this.imagesBox.style.display = 'none';
        this.images = this.product.querySelectorAll('img');

        this.event = function() {
            function startSlider(elem,i) {
                function getImgSrc(src) {
                    var arrSrc = [];
                    for(var i = 0; i < self.images.length; i++) {
                        arrSrc.push(self.images[i].getAttribute(src));
                    }
                    return arrSrc;
                }
                var src = getImgSrc('src');
                var srcset = getImgSrc('srcset');
                elem.setAttribute('src', src[i]);
                elem.setAttribute('srcset', srcset[i]);
                if(i == self.images.length - 1) {
                    i = 0;
                } else {
                    i++;
                }
                var timer = setTimeout(startSlider, 1000, elem, i);
                self.product.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                    //непонятно как то устанавливает значения атрибутов, ведь должен при уходе мыши ставить 
                    //первые элементы соответствующих массивов,
                    //а ставит предшествующую показанной.
                    elem.setAttribute('src', src[0]);
                    elem.setAttribute('srcset', srcset[0]);
                });
            }
            self.product.addEventListener('mouseover', function (event) {
                if(event.target == self.product.querySelector('img')) {
                    var i = 1;
                    startSlider(event.target, i);
                }
                else return;
            });
        }
        this.event();

    }
}

function Products(ids) {
    this.products = document.querySelector(ids);
    if(!this.products)return;
    for(var i = 0; i < this.products.children.length; i++) {
        //присвоение происходит только последнему ребенку коллекции, почему?Точнее метод event класса Product работает только на последнем элементе.
        this.products.children[i] = new Product(this.products.children[i], '.thumbnails');
    }
}
var products = new Products('.products');
```

Answer (score 1):

А что если события заменить на [mouseenter и mouseleave](https://learn.javascript.ru/mousemove-mouseover-mouseout-mouseenter-mouseleave#%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-mouseenter-%D0%B8-mouseleave)?

Comment: Думаю не подойдет, нет делегирования, по сути мышь заходит на <li>, в нем <а>, а уже в <a> лежит картинка.